# PHP: AWS SDK Class not found on production server

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, sdk

I installed AWS SDK along with Facebook and Google SDKs. All of them are working with no problem on my local MacOs environment. But once I pushed to our server all AWS clients are not working. FB and Google still working on production.

```
include_once(__DIR__ . "/../../../vendor/autoload.php");
use Aws\Rekognition\RekognitionClient;
use Aws\Sdk;
class RekognitionTest extends CI_Controller
{
private $client;

function __construct()
{
    $sharedConfig = [
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
        'credentials' => [
            'key' => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            'secret' => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        ]
    ];
    $sdk = new Sdk($sharedConfig);
    $this->client = $sdk->createRekognition();
 }
}
```

in the above code I am getting error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Aws\Sdk' not found

Also tried different ways to initiate the client using:

```
$this->client = new RekognitionClient([
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region' => 'us-east-1',
            'credentials' => [
                'key' => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                'secret' => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            ]
        ]);
```

With the second way I am getting :

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Aws\Rekognition\RekognitionClient' not found

SDK version: **"aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.82"**

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Have you run `composer install` command?

Comment: I ran it on my local when I installed the sdk but not on the server. I just pushed the code via git

Comment: It's likely that you ignore your `vendor` folder from committing to your git repo. Try to run `composer install` on your AWS server.

Comment: No, vendor is not ignored. because FB and Google sdks are installed via composer on my local and they working with no issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on [AWS SDK PHP Class Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32085925/2259546). I deleted SDK downloaded via composer and installed it again from .zip https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/releases and that worked perfectly. I am not sure why composer files are different from zip file.